# Shape property "decorative" not in VSTO?

Tags: powerpoint, vsto, shapes, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I program PowerPoint add-ins both in VBA and in VSTO. In VBA I can use shape.Decorative to check, if a shape is decorative - and therefore does not need an alternative text. In VSTO however there is no such property.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, the reference to PowerPoint is set to version 15.0.0.0.0 - but I can't see where I could change that. Am I using the wrong template?

I'm grateful for any tips how to get to that attribute. Thanks in advance, Sabina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerPoint object model provides the [Shape.Decorative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.decorative) property which sets or returns the decorative flag for the specified object. So, it doesn't matter whether it is a VSTO add-ins or VBA macro. The PowerPoint object model is common for all programming languages. In this situation you can:

1. Use a newer PIA to get access to the property (with intellisense suggestions).
2. Use the late-binding technology to invoke the property programmatically even when it is not available in PIAs. The [Type.InvokeMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember?view=net-6.0) method invokes a specific member of the current `Type`.

Comment: It worked via late binding, thanks a lot!